# How to write a regex in java for a String with parenthesis?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse a C language code in java and I encountered statements like

```
printf("hello world");
```

I was using `Pattern.compile("printf/(/".*/"/)");` but was getting an error stating that

> /( is not a valid escape sequence

Please give a way to tackle this kind of scenario.

Comment: use backslash to escape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape a character, you need to use backslash instead of forward slash. Since `(` is a special meta character, you need to escape that also.

```
Pattern.compile("printf\\(\".*?\"\\);");
```

Example:

```
String value = "printf(\"hello world\");";
System.out.println(value.matches("printf\\(\".*?\"\\);"));
//=> true
```